# Delay Signing on Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I want to use delayed signing for my windows mobile compact framework assemblies.

When you sign an assembly using delayed signing it signs it with the public key and leaves space in the assembly for the private keys, which can be added just before shipping the assembly.

A delay signed assembly can not be run or debugged unless the signing is completed or verification for that assembly is turned of on that machine using.

sn -Vr assemblyName.dll

However this is a windows mobile application and I'm not running the assembly on my machine I'm running it on my windows mobile device.

Is their a way to run a delay signed assembly on windows mobile or is delay signing not really supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay signing is not supported in the Compact Framework (at least not as of 3.5).

Edit: To be more specific, while you can [build it with no private key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180781.aspx), there is no way to [register the assembly on the device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx) for verification skipping.  So you could still delay sign a CF assembly when it's used on the desktop (since it's retargetable, that's an option).  Not sure how useful that would ever be though.